# How to project a 3D point onto a plane along another (axis) vector?

Tags: computational-geometry

I have a point $P = (0, y, z)$. I need to determine the $x$ coordinate of its projection $P'$ onto a plane $T$ along the $x$ axis unit vector $\vec{X} = (1, 0, 0)$. The plane $T$ is defined by a point $V$ that lies on $T$ and its normal $\vec{N}$ (see the attached picture).

[image: Projection onto plane along a vector.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can determine `x` by calculating line-plane intersection. Your line starts at `P` and has direction `D=[1, 0, 0]`, and plane `T=[V, N]`. This can be done as follows:
$$x=\frac{(V-P)\cdot N}{N\cdot D}$$
`x` is the distance from `P` along `D` to the intersection point with `T` (assuming both `D` and `N` are unit vectors)